# Select and Update MAC Addresses to Same Format

Tags: mysql, update, query, bulk

I have a mysql database with a `macaddress` column, this contains thousands of mac addresses in various formats; uppercase, lowercase and with colons. See below for an example;

```
+-------------------+
| macaddress        |
+-------------------+
| 90CCAADD3341      |
+-------------------+
| 90:3f:ff:11:22:33 |
+-------------------+
| 33:44:aa:bb:34:6a |
+-------------------+
| 8801abcd3231      |
+-------------------+
```

Is there any way I can bulk update all rows in this column so they are in the same format?

I'd like them all to be uppercase with no colons, see below;

```
+--------------+
| macaddress   |
+--------------+
| 90CCAADD3341 |
+--------------+
| 903FFF112233 |
+--------------+
| 3344AABB346A |
+--------------+
| 8801ABCD3231 |
+--------------+
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test select:

```
select macaddress, upper(replace(macaddress,':','')) as new_macaddress
from Macs;
```

Update:

```
update macs
set macaddress = upper(replace(macaddress,':',''));
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63bb688dc97196837d1b2b6b4e2aa051)

Test data:

```
create table macs
(
macaddress varchar(20)
);

insert into macs values('90CCAADD3341');

insert into macs values('90:3f:ff:11:22:33');

insert into macs values('33:44:aa:bb:34:6a');

insert into macs values('8801abcd3231');
```

Documentation links:

[UPPER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper)

[REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Comment: Perfect thank you!